# Position an element relative to its container

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to create a horizontal 100% stacked bar graph using HTML and CSS. I'd like to create the bars using `DIVs` with background colors and percentage widths depending on the values I want to graph. I also want to have a grid lines to mark an arbitrary position along the graph.

In my experimentation, I've already gotten the bars to stack horizontally by assigning the CSS property `float: left`. However, I'd like to avoid that, as it really seems to mess with the layout in confusing ways. Also, the grid lines don't seem to work very well when the bars are floated.

I think that CSS positioning should be able to handle this, but I don't yet know how to do it. I want to be able to specify the position of several elements relative to the top-left corner of their container. I run into this sort of issue regularly (even outside of this particular graph project), so I'd like a method that's:

1. Cross-browser (ideally without too many browser hacks)
2. Runs in Quirks mode
3. As clear/clean as possible, to facilitate customizations
4. Done without JavaScript if possible.

Comment: Do you have to do it in HTML? could you use google charts instead? http://code.google.com/apis/chart/#bar_charts

Answer (score 405, accepted):

You are right that CSS positioning is the way to go. Here's a quick run down:

`position: relative` will layout an element relative to *itself.* In other words, the elements is laid out in normal flow, then it is removed from normal flow and offset by whatever values you have specified (top, right, bottom, left). It's important to note that because it's removed from flow, other elements around it will not shift with it (use negative margins instead if you want this behaviour).

However, you're most likely interested in `position: absolute` which will position an element relative to a container. By default, the container is the browser window, but if a parent element either has `position: relative` or `position: absolute` set on it, then it will act as the parent for positioning coordinates for its children.

To demonstrate:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box">absolute</div>
</div>
```

In that example, the top left corner of `#box` would be 100px down and 50px left of the top left corner of `#container`. If `#container` did not have `position: relative` set, the coordinates of `#box` would be relative to the top left corner of the browser view port.

Comment: This page shows nice illustrations of this phenomenon: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 23):

You have to explicitly set the position of the parent container along with the position of the child container.  The typical way to do that is something like this:

```css
div.parent{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;  /* stick it wherever it was positioned by default */
    top: 0px;
}

div.child{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to provide top or left property values for relatively positioned elements if they are zero.

Comment: True for existing browsers but not defined in the specification.

Comment: It is certainly defined in the specification.  Read section 9.4.3 and check the initial values for the properties.

Comment: 9.4.3 says that the initial values for left and top are 'auto'.  The definition of what happens to 'auto' values is sort of convoluted, and I've never been able to fully understand them.  I'll take your word for it if you say that it winds up being zero, though.

Answer (score 18):

I know I am late but hope this helps.

Following are the values for the position property.

- static
- fixed
- relative
- absolute

**position : static**

This is default. It means the element will occur at a position that it normally would.

```
#myelem {
    position : static;
}
```

**position : fixed**

This will set the position of an element with respect to the browser window (viewport). A fixed positioned element will remain in its position even when the page scrolls.

(Ideal if you want scroll-to-top button at the bottom right corner of the page).

```
#myelem {
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 30px;
    right : 30px;
}
```

**position : relative**

To place an element at a new location relative to its original position.

```
#myelem {
    position : relative;
    left : 30px;
    top : 30px;
}
```

The above CSS will move the #myelem element 30px to the left and 30px from the top of its actual location.

**position : absolute**

If we want an element to be placed at an exact position in the page.

```
#myelem {
    position : absolute;
    top : 30px;
    left : 300px;
}
```

The above CSS will position #myelem element at a position 30px from top and 300px from the left in the page and it will scroll with the page.

And finally...

**position relative + absolute**

We can set the position property of a parent element to *relative* and then set the position property of the child element to *absolute*. This way we can position the child relative to the parent at an absolute position.

```
#container {
    position : relative;
}

#div-2 {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    right : 0;
}
```

[image: Absolute position of a child element w.r.t. a Relative positioned parent element.]

We can see in the above image the **#div-2** element is positioned at the top-right corner inside the **#container** element.

GitHub: You can find the HTML of the above image [here](https://github.com/yusufshakeel/css-project/blob/master/position.html) and CSS [here](https://github.com/yusufshakeel/css-project/blob/master/css/position.css).

Hope this [tutorial](https://www.dyclassroom.com/css/css-position) helps.

Answer (score 3):

Absolute positioning positions an element relative to its nearest positioned ancestor.  So put `position: relative` on the container, then for child elements, `top` and `left` will be relative to the top-left of the container so long as the child elements have `position: absolute`.  More information is available in [the CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to position an element relative to its containing element first you need to add `position: relative` **to the container element**. The child element you want to position relatively to the parent **has to have** `position: absolute`. The way that absolute positioning works is that **it is done relative to the first relatively (or absolutely) positioned parent element**. In case there is **no relatively** positioned parent, the element will be positioned relative to the **root element** (directly to the HTML element).

So if you want to position your child element to the top left of the parent container, you should do this:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
} 

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
}
```

You will benefit greatly from reading [this article](https://kolosek.com/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute/). Hope this helps!