# How can I position an element at the bottom of its container in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a table cell, and I want a div within it to always be at the bottom left corner.  The following works fine in IE and Safari, but Firefox is positioning the `div` absolutely on the page, not within the cell (code based on the solution solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css)).  I have tested both with and without the DTD, which put Firefox in Quirks mode and Standards mode, and neither worked properly.  I'm stuck - any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        table { width:500px; }
        th, td { vertical-align: top; border:1px solid black; position:relative; }
        th { width:100px; }
        .manage { text-align:right; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Some info about the following thing and this is actually going to span a few lines</th>
            <td><p>A short blurb</p><div class="manage">Edit | Delete</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Some info about the following thing and this is actually going to span a few lines</th>
            <td><p>A short blurb</p><div class="manage">Edit | Delete</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found the way to do this?

Comment: Sorry to hear that... I finally ended up adding a new borderless "<TR>" to hold the bottom-content.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position), position:relative has no effect on table cells:

> "The effect of 'position:relative' on
>   table-row-group, table-header-group,
>   table-footer-group, table-row,
>   table-column-group, table-column,
>   table-cell, and table-caption elements
>   is undefined."

The solution is to add an extra wrapping div to the table cell.

**EDIT:** This div requires a `height:100%` and `position:relative;` to be set.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="position:relative;height:100%;">
                Normal inline content.
                <div class="manage">your absolute-positioned content</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That doesn't push it to the bottom :(

Comment: edited code example now. I tested this in Firefox 3 and it works.

Comment: In FF3, this is not pushing to the bottom for me.  http://i36.tinypic.com/znqxpv.jpg

Comment: `height:100%` does *precisely nothing* in this context.  See [CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html): "If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'"  Therefore, as the parent `td` does not have explicit height, the div's height is calculated as the height of its content, regardless of the 100% specification.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you. Not sure of the exact ature of the problem but it has something to do with using td with relative positioning. I wrapped the table with div tag and positioned that relatively and it seems to do what you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        table { width:500px;  }
        th, td { vertical-align: top; border:1px solid black; }
        th { width:100px; }
        div.body {position:relative; width:500px;}
        .manage { text-align:right; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; display:block}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
    <div class="body"><table>
        <tr>
                <th>Some info about the following thing and this is actually going to span a few lines</th>
                <td><p>A short blurb</p><div class="manage">Edit | Delete</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this one breaks when I add another row to the table that looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `display:block` on the table and now FF respects the position:relative.

Comment: In FF18, this causes the table not to maintain its width, and the elements are positioned absolutely on the offset parent of the table (in this case, the window)

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative` is apparently not globally supported for the `td` tag. I couldn't find definitive sources unfortunately.

You might want to put a `div` block into the `td` with the desired size and apply `position: relative` to that instead.

Comment: Trying this, I can't get the div to fill the td.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound really obvious, but have you tried using `vertical-align: bottom;` in .manage?

Answer (score 0):

have a DIV inside the TD with width: 100% and height: 100%, then set that to position: relative.

Comment: This does not work - the inner div does not get pushed to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Right, position:relative has no effect for table elements, and firefox apply this rule.
The solution of the div works, but this is terrible markup in my opinion.

Do you absolutely need to use a table to display this content? (Or is it relative?)

If not, why don't you use div elements and do what you want?

To use tables for layout issues is so 1998...

Comment: The data I am displaying is tabular.  One column displays context for a comment, the other column displays the comment itself.  Why use an element with no semantic meaning when a semantically rich one is provided, that fits my case?

Comment: Ok, but a definition list (dl) instead of a table can be a semantic solution as well.

Comment: They are not really definitions.  Is there a way to make sure both dt and dd stay the same height as content changes?

Comment: This can be a solution:
http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/definition/dl-table-display.htm

Comment: I got very excited - it seemed to do everything I needed.  Even got a border between the left and right sides (dt and dd).  Unfortunately, if the dt content is longer than the dd content it breaks in IE.