# Make a DIV fill an entire table cell

Tags: css

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291537/how-can-i-get-a-div-to-fill-a-table-cell-vertically) and [googled a bit](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+fill+a+table+cell+with+a+div), but nothing so far has worked. I figure it's 2010 now (those questions/answers are old and, well, unanswered) and we have CSS3! Is there any way to get a div to fill an entire table cell's width and height using CSS?

I don't know what the width and/or height of the cell will be ahead of time, and setting the div's width and height to 100% does not work.

Also, the reason I need the div is because I need to absolutely position some elements outside of the cell, and `position: relative` does not apply to `td`s, so I need a wrapper div.

Comment: Does the container of the table itself have a specific height? Does the table span the viewport of the page?

Comment: It is really odd that setting the height and width to 100% doesn't work.  That should make the div the full width and height of the parent tag.  Maybe this isn't working because of the relative positioning.  I'm curious to see the solution when someone finds it.

Comment: @meder the data in the table is dynamic, so i will never know the height. the width fills the screen, yes.

Comment: Non-scripting wise I bet the only way would be to either make the table fill the whole viewport somehow, or have a nested table inside the td, or rely on some weird quirksmode IE exploit.

Comment: You might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841484/how-can-a-label-completely-fill-its-parent-td/3074320

Comment: @Marcin If the height of the table-cell (ie. the container) is not explicitly stated then a pc% height on the inner DIV is actually computed as 'auto' - according to the spec.

Comment: You will probably have to rely on JS unless you can make the table span the viewport.

Comment: Just get the size of the cell or the size of the viewport and set it to your div. I use this in a web site on which i display a map, always filling the browser window (I set both td height and div).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The following code works on IE 8, IE 8's IE 7 compatibility mode, and Chrome (not tested elsewhere):

```
<table style="width:100px"> <!-- Not actually necessary; just makes the example text shorter -->
   <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="padding:0;">
         <div style="height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#abc; position:relative;">
            <img style="left:90px; position:absolute;" src="../Content/Images/attachment.png"/>
            test of really long content that causes the height of the cell to increase dynamically
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>test</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You said in your original question that setting `width` and `height` to `100%` didn't work, though, which makes me suspect that there is some other rule overriding it. Did you check the computed style in Chrome or Firebug to see if the width/height rules were really being applied?

### Edit

How foolish I am! The `div` was sizing to the text, not to the `td`. You can fix this on Chrome by making the `div` `display:inline-block`, but it doesn't work on IE. That's proving trickier...

Comment: sigh... good call on checking if other styles were being applied. apparently i had some padding rules that were preventing my div from spanning the whole table cell. once i got rid of those, i had no problems. i was curious because my code looks just like yours (using classes of course), but when i went further up the chain, lo and behold, padding. thanks for your help.

Comment: try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2K2tG/ notice how the cell w/the image is red and not #abc. width/height 100% does nothing

Comment: Yeah this works with Chrome, but not for Firefox unfortunately... http://jsfiddle.net/38Ngn/1/

Answer (score 119):

I had to **set a *fake* height to the `<tr>` and height: inherit for `<td>s`**

tr has **`height: 1px`** (it's ignored anyway)

Then set the td **`height: inherit`**

Then set the div to **`height: 100%`**

This worked for me in IE edge and Chrome:

```html
<table style="width:200px;">
    <tr style="height: 1px;">
        <td style="height: inherit; border: 1px solid #000; width: 100px;">
            <div>
              Something big with multi lines and makes table bigger
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="height: inherit; border: 1px solid #000; width: 100px;">
            <div style="background-color: red; height: 100%;">
                full-height div
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't know if this always works, but it did work for me in IE 11.

Comment: I just needed `td {  height: 1px  }` for Chrome.

Comment: This doesn't work for Firefox, you have to set `height: 100%` instead of `inherit` on th/td cell. But then it won't work in chrome/safari etc. :-). I have used `@supports (height: -mo-available)` to actually target firefox and set the height in the query.

Comment: @TomášPustelník thanks! That worked like a charm. But there is a small typo, it's `@supports (height: -moz-available)`.

Comment: @andzep you are right, thanks for finding this typo.

Comment: Does not work with FireFox, imo @supports feels hacky. I would go with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73399942/4316681

Answer (score 91):

div height=100% in table cell will work only when table has height attribute itself.

```html
<table border="1" style="height:300px; width: 100px;">
 <tr><td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td></tr>
 <tr>
   <td style="height: 100%">
     <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color:pink;"></div>
   </td>
   <td>long text long text long text long text long text long text</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**UPD** in FireFox you should also set `height=100%` value to the parent `TD` element

Comment: Good trick, but worked only on Chromium for me. IE9 & firefox 19 aren't able to stretch the div.

Comment: instead of using a pixel height, i used 100% height and a min-height:1px.

Comment: If you set the containing `td` height to `100%` as well, it should work in FF. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Downvoted, doesn't work. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/da8aL2hk/ Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CwLnK.png

Comment: You'll need to add a 100% height to the `<tr>` as well.

Comment: Kaperstone's answer is much simpler and works very nicely

Answer (score 68):

So, because everyone is posting their solution and none was good for me, here is mine (tested on Chrome & Firefox).

```css
table { height: 1px; } /* Will be ignored, don't worry. */
tr { height: 100%; }
td { height: 100%; }
td > div { height: 100%; }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nh6g5fzv/

--

**Edit**: one thing you might want to note, if you want to apply a padding to the div in the td, you must add `box-sizing: border-box;` because of `height: 100%`.

Comment: Worked great for a while in my case, until recently Chrome started actually cutting down the table's height to 1px, effectively making it unusable. Not entirely sure what is going on here, just be careful when using this

Comment: I'm testing on Chromium 87 and it's still working, are you sure that your table still has `display: table;`? Or maybe we need to try on a development version of Chrome?

Comment: This works for me in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Edge. Thanks

Comment: This is the complete and proper solution! Thanks, mate! :)

Comment: I found you can also set table height to `100%` and that works too (tested in Chrome & Firefox).

Answer (score 28):

Since most of the solutions in this place are incorrect, the top answer is not even solving the issue and the chosen answer doesn't work.

To solve the issue in the shortest way possible, set `table` height to `fit-content`
the `table-row` height to `100%` and you're done.

Works on Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Example:

```html
<table style="height:fit-content">
    <tr style="height:100%">
        <td>
            <div style="height:100%"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked like charm! For me it worked fine with just `height:fit-content` to the `<table>`, did not need to apply any style to `<tr>`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Had to add `height:100%` on the th to work in FireFox.

Comment: This answer is the only correct here.

Comment: This is the way to go!

Comment: FF doesn't support height: fit-content as of Jan 2023. caniuse.com/?search=fit%20content. But setting the <tr> height to 100% did it for me! Thanks!

Comment: FF supports it now

Answer (score 15):

If your reason for wanting a 100% div inside a table cell was to be able to have a background color extend to the full height but still be able to have spacing between the cells, you could give the `<td>` itself the background color and use the CSS border-spacing property to create the margin between the cells.

If you truly need a 100% height div, however, then as others here have mentioned you need to either assign a fixed height to the `<table>` or use Javascript.

Comment: you could space the cell by using `border-spacing:5px` on the "table"ed element, but I agree, using a DIV inside the cells is much more elegant and overall better to have.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, works just fine. just remember to apply `border-collapse: separate` to the table, otherwise it wont have any effect. +1

Comment: `border-collapse: separate` is the default, but yes, that's a good tip.

Answer (score 8):

if `<table> <tr> <td> <div>` all have `height: 100%;` set, then the div will fill the dynamic cell height in all browsers.

Comment: Why does this work?? 

Answer (score 6):

Since every other browser (including IE 7, 8 and 9) handles `position:relative` on a table cell correctly and *only* Firefox gets it wrong, your best bet is to use a JavaScript shim.  You shouldn’t have to alter your DOM for one failed browser.  People use shims all the time when IE gets something wrong and all the other browsers get it right.

Here is a snippet with all the code annotated. The JavaScript, HTML and CSS use responsive web design practices in my example, but you don’t have to if you don’t want. (Responsive means it adapts to your browser width.)

http://jsfiddle.net/mrbinky3000/MfWuV/33/

Here is the code itself, but it doesn’t make sense without the context, so visit the jsfiddle URL above. (The full snippet also has plenty of comments in both the CSS and the Javascript.)

```
$(function() {
    // FireFox Shim
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        $('#test').wrapInner('<div class="ffpad"></div>');
        function ffpad() {
            var $ffpad = $('.ffpad'),
                $parent = $('.ffpad').parent(),
                w, h;
            $ffpad.height(0);
            if ($parent.css('display') == 'table-cell') {               
                h = $parent.outerHeight();
                $ffpad.height(h);
            }
        }
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            ffpad();
        });
        ffpad();
    }
});
```

Comment: While this was a good answer, do not copy/paste this code. $.browser has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8 and was removed in 1.9. For more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: I like this answer as well, but like @cmegown said, $.browser is now deprecated. What I'd personally do instead(I'll try that - I'm not 100% sure it will work) would be to change the positioning of the element from static to absolute(or the other way around) and see if there is a change in the position of the element compared to the window. This should only work if the element has `top:0; left: 0;`.

Comment: I can confirm that that worked for me - I get the element's .offset() and then change it to position absolute and get it's offset() again and if it's not the same, I wrap it up in a position: relative div. 
This only works because when positioned absolutely I don't expect my element to change it's positioning(since it's top: 0; left: 0;)

Comment: Firefox does not "get it wrong". Relatively positioning a table cell is undefined in the CSS spec. ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position))

Answer (score 3):

after several days searching I figured out a possible fix for this issue.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body style="height:100%">
<!-- for Firefox and Chrome compatibility set height:100% in the containing TABLE, the TR parent and the TD itself. -->
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height:100%;">  
  <tr>
    <td>whatever</td>
    <td>whatever</td>
    <td>whatever</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:100%;">
    <td>whatever dynamic height<br /><br /><br />more content
</td>
    <td>whatever</td>

    <!-- display,background-color and radius properties in TD BELOW could be placed in an <!--[if IE]> commentary If desired.
    This way TD would remain as display:table-cell; in FF and Chrome and would keep working correctly.    
    If you don't place the properties in IE commentary it will still work in FF and Chorme with a TD display:block;

    The Trick for IE is setting the cell to display:block; Setting radius is only an example of whay you may want a DIV 100%height inside a Cell.
    -->

    <td style="height:100%; width:100%; display:block; background-color:#3C3;border-radius: 0px 0px 1em 0px;">

    <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#3C3;-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0.6em 0px;border-radius: 0px 0px 0.6em 0px;">
    Content inside DIV TAG
    </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Spanish language:
El truco es establecer la Tabla, el TR y el TD a height:100%. Esto lo hace compatible con FireFox y Chrome. Internet Explorer ignora eso, por lo que ponemos la etiqueta TD como block. De esta forma Explorer sí toma la altura máxima.

English explanation: within the code commentaries

Answer (score 3):

I propose a solution using <del>the experimental</del> [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) to *simulate* a table layout which will allow a cell's content element to fill up its parent cell vertically:

### Demo

```css
.table{ display:flex; border:2px solid red; }
.table > *{ flex: 1; border:2px solid blue; position:relative; }
.fill{ background:lightgreen; height:100%; position:absolute; left:0; right:0; }

/* Reset */
*{ padding:0; margin:0; }
body{ padding:10px; }
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <aside><div class='fill'>Green should be 100% height</div></aside>
  <aside></aside>
  <aside>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus conguet.</p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I do not have enough reputation to post a comment, I want to add a complete cross-browser solution that combined @Madeorsk and @Saadat's approaches with some slight modification! (Tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, and Edge as of 2/10/2020)

```
table { height: 1px; }
tr { height: 100%; }
td { height: 100%; }
td > div { 
   height: -webkit-calc(100vh);
   height: -moz-calc(100vh);
   height: calc(100%);
   width: 100%;
    background: pink;  // This will show that it works!
}
```

However, if you're like me, than you want to control vertical alignment as well, and in those cases, I like to use flexbox:

```
td > div {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok nobody mentioned this so I figured I would post this trick:

```
.tablecell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.tablecell div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**overflow:auto** on that container div within the cell does the trick for me. Without it the div does not use the entire height.

Answer (score 0):

To make height:100% work for the inner div, you have to set a height for the parent td. For my particular case it worked using height:100%. This made the inner div height stretch, while the other elements of the table didn't allow the td to become too big. You can of course use other values than 100%

If you want to also make the table cell have a fixed height so that it does not get bigger based on content (to make the inner div scroll or hide overflow), that is when you have no choice but do some js tricks. The parent td will need to have the height specified in a non relative unit (not %). And you will most probably have no choice but to calculate that height using js. This would also need the table-layout:fixed style set for the table element

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar issues frequently and always just use `table-layout: fixed;` on the `table` element and `height: 100%;` on the inner div.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately found nothing that would work across all my browsers and all DocTypes / browser rendering modes, except for using jQuery. So here is what I came up with.
It even takes rowspan into account.

```
function InitDivHeights() {
    var spacing = 10; // <-- Tune this value to match your tr/td spacing and padding.
    var rows = $('#MyTable tr');
    var heights = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        heights[i] = $(rows[i]).height();
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = $(rows[i]);
        var cells = $('td', row);
        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            var cell = $(cells[j]);
            var rowspan = cell.attr('rowspan') || 1;
            var newHeight = 0;
            for (var k = 0; (k < rowspan && i + k < heights.length); k++)
                newHeight += heights[i + k];
            $('div', cell).height(newHeight - spacing);
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(InitDivHeights);
```

Tested in IE11 (Edge mode), FF42, Chrome44+. Not tested with nested tables.

Comment: well, now this is easy with flexbox. this is an old question!

Comment: @Jason thanks, but we needed it to work in IE10/IE11 as well, which both have partial / buggy flexbox support according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox and also https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs. Maybe later...

Answer (score 0):

If the table cell is the size that you want, just add this css class and assign it to your div:

```
.block {
   height: -webkit-calc(100vh);
   height: -moz-calc(100vh);
   height: calc(100vh);
   width: 100%;
}
```

If you want the table cell to fill up the parent too, assign the class to the table cell too.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that:

```
<td>
  <div style="width: 100%; position: relative; float: left;">inner div</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late to the party but here's my solution:

```
<td style="padding: 0; position: relative;">
   <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; overflow: auto;">
     AaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBbbbbbbbCCCCCCCCCccccc<br>
     DDDDDDDddddEEEEEEEEdddfffffffffgggggggggggggggggggg
   </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the positioned element and its father element do not have width and height, then set

```
padding: 0;
```

in its father element,

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not recommended.

I figured out a workaround which works if your div doesn't contain text and has an uniform background.

```
display: 'list-item'
```

gives the div the desired height and width, but with the big downside of having a list item bullet. Since the div has a homogeneous background-color I got rid of the bullet with those styles:

```
list-style-position: 'inside',
color: *background-color*,
```

Answer (score 0):

This hack works for me : juste put a space in the div (then it takes all the height of the td)

```
<td>
   <div>
     &nbsp;
     <!-- some optional content filled by vuejs, angular or what you want -->
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: This won't consistently work once you start adding more items in the row as it may make the row higher. In your example it will work but I'd say that's misleading for real world usage. You shouldn't be using `&nbsp;` to hack layouts.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you want to do but you might try this one:

`<td width="661" valign="top"><div>Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div></td>`

Answer (score -1):

The following should work. You have to set a height to the parent cell.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrvd3vgd/

```
<table style="width:200px; border: 1px solid #000;">
    <tr>
        <td style="height:100px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:200px;">
            <div style="height:100%; background: #f00;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<td style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;width:100%;"></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that the best solution would be to use JavaScript.

But I'm not sure that you need to do this to solve your problem of positioning elements in the `<td>` outside of the cell. For that you could do something like this:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="position:absolute;bottom:-100px">hello world</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Not inline of course, but with classes and ids.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works if I need to place something relative to the _table_. I need to place something outside an individual _cell_ where the cell's location is unknown.

Comment: can you expand on what this table contains? and what the 100% width/height thing is?

Answer (score -2):

I does not watch here an old CSS-trick for <**div**> inside <**td**>. Hence I remind: simple set some minimal value for **width**, but *what-you-need* for **min-width**. For example:

```
<div style="width: 3px; min-width: 99%;">
```

The **td**'s width, in that case, is up to you.

Answer (score -9):

This is my Solution for extend 100% height and 100% width in a html `<td>`

if you delete the first line in your code you can fix it ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

because this doctype does not permit in some files to use the 100% percent inside of `<td>`, but if you delete this line, the body fails expanding the background to 100% height and 100% width, so I found this `DOCTYPE` that solves the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

this DOCTYPE let you extends the background in your body as 100% height and 100% width, and let you take all the 100% height and 100% width into the `<td>`

Comment: Better not to mess with the doctype. You don't seem to be aware of all the consequences. Changing Doctypes can have a lot of side effects (so does most things in CSS world, deplorably).