# IE8 Cell Corner Border

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, html-table, border

I'm attempting to display a column separator for a table in IE8. I'm using CSS which works great in Chrome and Firefox but in IE8 the corner of the table cells with the black column separator appear differently. You can view the differences in the the below images. The first image is from IE8 which is showing the results that I do not want and the second image is from Chrome which shows how I want the table to appear.

[image]

[image]

The source is below, you can also edit it at http://jsbin.com/obava4/2/edit:

```
table.testresults 
{
     border-collapse:collapse;
}


table.testresults td {
    padding: 3px;
    border-style:solid;    
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color:lightgray;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight:400;
}

table.testresults *.borderleft {
    border-left-color: black;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 5px;

}

table.testresults th { 
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 3px;
    spacing:0px;
    border-bottom-color: lightgray;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color:lightgray;
}

</style>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>


</head>

<body>
<table class="testresults">
          <col id="col1"><col id="col2"><col id="col3">
          <tr class="currenv">
            <th class="corrcorrenv borderleft" align="left" colspan="1">CORR of COR</th>
            <th class="correnv borderleft" align="left" colspan="1">CORR</th>

          </tr>
      <tr class="currenv">
        <th width="50px" class="resultheader borderleft" align="left">Result</th>
        <th class="nowrap">Age &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="borderleft" TestResultsID="">Pased</td>
    <td>row.ARAge</td>


 </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's just the way IE renders table cell borders. Alternatively, you could try wrapping the cell content in a div and giving the borders to the div, but it's quite a challenge to get divs to fill a table cell - reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215553/make-a-div-fill-an-entire-table-cell) SO question.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: It's interesting, you'd think they'd have fixed it in IE9. Oh well.