# Have Table-cell DIV height 100% of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div set as a table, and a child-div set as a table-cell. I need the table-cell (in this case, `#tv`) to be 100% of the parent (`#news`). My `.news-inner` div will be alternating in height based on what content is included (Could be 6 `li`, could be 20). I'm not sure what is missing, and I'm sure it's something incredibly easy that I've overlooked at quarter to four in the morning.

I'd prefer a solution that didn't involve JavaScript like one of the answers provided in this question, [How to make a div inside a table cell "height: 100%"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521660/how-to-make-a-div-inside-a-table-cell-height-100). CSS prefered, but I'm no dictator

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/neagbj13/)

```
<div class="box" id="news">
    <div class="news-inner">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tv">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally,

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
#news { width: 800px; background: #ccc; }
#news .news-inner {width: 75%; display: inline-block; }
#news ul { list-style: none; width: 100%; padding: 15px; font-size: 0;  }
#news ul li { font-size: 14px; display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 150px; vertical-align: top }
#news ul li:nth-child(1) { background: #c6c; }
#news ul li:nth-child(2) { background: #000; }
#tv { width: 25%; height: 100%; display: block;  background: #c6c; float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `display:table` to `#news`, and from `#tv` I removed `float:right;display:block` and added `display:inline-block`.

Also notice the *HTML comments* that removes the *whitespace*.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
#news { width: 800px; background: #ccc; display:table }
#news .news-inner {width: 75%; display: inline-block; }
#news ul { list-style: none; width: 100%; padding: 15px; font-size: 0;  }
#news ul li { font-size: 14px; display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 150px; vertical-align: top }
#news ul li:nth-child(1) { background: #c6c; }
#news ul li:nth-child(2) { background: #000; }
#tv { width: 25%; height: 100%; background: #c6c; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
```

```html
<div class="box" id="news">
    <div class="news-inner">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--
    --><div id="tv">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poke6wht/1)

---

[Fiddle with 20 `li` elements](http://jsfiddle.net/poke6wht/2/)