# position:absolute, inside a display:table-cell with a dynamic height in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a horizontal layout that I'm using `display: table-cell` with to get a uniform height. This looks fine in Chrome, but I cannot get IE to render similarly.

http://jsfiddle.net/z8hys/4/

This is what I intend for it to look like:
[image: Chrome jsfiddle image].

But in IE9, IE10, and IE11 I get something that looks like this:
[image: IE jsfiddle image]

- Height of `.cell` needs to be dynamic.
- Needs to work in at least IE.
- Vertical dotted line, `.top`, has a variable height.
- Horizontal dotted line, `.right`, has a variable position.

Comment: In my testing, it appears that there is no (non-hack) way to make this work right in IE10.  Check out this question, may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18248214/870729

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely other ways to get a uniform-heighted layout without using `display:table-cell` which work significantly better in IE11-. But it's hard for me to suggest one because I have no idea what the two little dotted lines are meant to denote or why they'd there.

But one suggestion, would be: http://jsfiddle.net/zq4EA/3/. Take a look and let me know if it doesn't work and why, and I'd be happy to keep working with you :) Hope that helps!

Comment: The height needs to be determined by the contents of the .cell's.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just put that `height:100px` for my little testing purposes. Are there specific widths the cells are supposed to take? For example, are they supposed to be two evenly-spaced columns? This fiddle has two evenly space columns: http://jsfiddle.net/zq4EA/5/