# IE 10 , div does not take 100% height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div structure which uses `display:table-row` and the last row is set to get the remaining height(100%) . This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 but not in IE10. Am I doing something wrong here ? [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raashid/e2rLmqu4/)

```
 <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">1</div>
            <div class="child">2</div>
            <div class="child">
                <div class="childTwo">
                    <div class="childTow-extra">132</div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
.parent{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.child{
    display: table-row;
}
.parent .child:nth-child(1){
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.parent .child:nth-child(2){
    height: 100px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.parent .child:nth-child(3){
    height: 100%;
    background: #555;
    margin: 10px;
}
.childTwo{
    height: 100%;
    background: red; 
}
.childTow-extra{
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;

}
```

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248214/content-of-element-not-100-in-ie10-inside-of-equal-height-columns

Comment: @DaveBurns, seems like this is related to equal size columns but for me it's rows , isn't it ?

Comment: The issue is [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27384730/1169519).