# height:100% inside table-cell not working on Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, web

I'm having some troubles trying to create a `div` with `height:100%` inside a wrap with `display:table-cell`.

I've noticed it doesn't work in Firefox and IE 9.

[Here's the fiddle with the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/54Jyp/1/). You can notice it works as expected and Chrome or Opera.

What's wrong with the code?

Is there any way to solve it?

I want to preserve the `display:table` and `display:table-cell` of the parents in order to center the content vertically on variable heights containers.

### HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://spaceinimages.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2012/11/solar_eclipse_corona/12092636-3-eng-GB/Solar_eclipse_corona_node_full_image.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215553/make-a-div-fill-an-entire-table-cell

Comment: also related, with a good answer, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For `height:100%` to work, all parent containers must be `height:100%`. If you notice, your `.table-cell` styles do not have `height:100%`.

Adding this style fixes the issue in Firefox:

```css
.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

As an alternative, adding the image to your HTML rather than as a CSS `background-image` might also work.

```css
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-size:cover;
}

.content img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="http://spaceinimages.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2012/11/solar_eclipse_corona/12092636-3-eng-GB/Solar_eclipse_corona_node_full_image.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="...your image url..." />
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
}

.content img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Mmm having some troubles with it in IE... let me try to replicate it on jsfiddle.

Comment: Well here you have it. `height:100%` and still having the problem. It would be solve using pixels, but i rather not. (check the second page scrolling down): http://jsfiddle.net/54Jyp/9/

Here a living example: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/prueba/examples/backgrounds.html

Remember to check it with IE 9.

Comment: On your live example, is your problem caused by the `padding-top:30%`?  I think I'm a little confused about the nature of the problem in your live environment.

Comment: I don't know what could be the problem. It seems it only takes place on IE though.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. This seems to be difficult to test so I will accept your answer anyway.

Answer (score -3):

You must set the `.content` and `.table .table-cell` classes as below

```
.content {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

.table, .table-cell {
    height: 100%;
}
```