# IE display: table-cell child ignores height: 100%

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I need to dynamically build a table to hold some data.
I've followed the usual approach of using divs with `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`:

```css
.tab {
    display: table;
    height:100%;
    width: 200px;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

.elem {
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
    background: blue;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    background: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="elem">
            <div class="content">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
            <div class="content">
                Longer content that will need to wrap around eventually you know and don't you hate it when things don't end as you expect them octopus
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Or view on Jsfiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eLo4ge1y/)

In most browsers I get the expected output:

[image: Sample image]

However, in IE8 (and possibly later versions, I haven't tested later versions), I get the following:

[image: Sample image 2]

The `height: 100%` set on the div surrounding *"Content"* is ignored.

According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table), IE8 should offer full support for the related display properties.

I've looked through a number of similar questions on SO without finding a working solution: most solutions either rely on Javascript (which I'm  looking to avoid), use a fixed height (ibid previous) or don't work on IE8.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento: It's not really a table. It just looks like one.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento The table will be used to hold tabular or semi-tabular data, what you're seeing is sample text to display the problem. You're missing the point of the question entirely.

Comment: try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8x347w73/ and use `p`for content, meanwhile take a look at this, it might help you: css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: @BoltClock Precisely for this reason I put "table" in quotation marks.

Comment: @Nit I did not miss anything, just is not clear in your question what you were trying to achieve and I asked the question just to make sure, that I was able to formulate an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, the effect of percentage values for `height` on `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` elements is undefined according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout):

> CSS 2.1 does not define how the height of table cells and table rows is calculated when their height is specified using percentage values.

So while a browser may claim to offer full support for table layout, certain aspects such as percentage heights may not be consistently implemented across all browsers because there is no correct behavior. You *could* try raising an issue on Microsoft Connect in hopes that they will change the behavior to be interoperable, but in the meantime you will need to find a different workaround (and even then you can't guarantee the behavior will remain interoperable, even in other browsers).

To make matters worse, I just tested and this affects all versions of IE up to and including 11, which means an IE-specific hack will fall short here. If you *need* to use a CSS table layout, as evidenced by the fact that you need to support IE8, then a pure CSS workaround is probably not feasible.

Comment: Ya just tested all versions from IE8 and up do the same behaviour

Answer (score 7):

For Internet Explorer 8-10 `table-cells` with `height: 100%;` have to be wrapped by `table-row` with `height: 100%;`.

Html for IE should be like:

```
table > table-row > table-cell
```

While other browsers will work properly with

```
table > table-row
or
table > table-cell
```

**[edit]** I reviewed the question again, and noticed You want to set 100% height not to the table-cells, but  on the content inside it.

**solution 1**: So for Internet Explorer content-height is related to closest element with height set in absolute units, such as pixels, em's, if you want to use % height, you may also need to set 100% height on all parent elements, this will be html and body.
[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eLo4ge1y/6/)

**solution 2**: Simply add

```
.content {
    padding-bottom: 9999px;
    margin-bottom: -9999px;
}
.elem {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You don't need to set height on Any of the parent elements in this case.
[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eLo4ge1y/7/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you'll refer to the question you'll see that is already the case and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nit I have reviewed your question again and added 2 solutions. I think the solution 2 is what you was looking for.

Comment: The hack only works when you can afford to hide the overflow, this is often not the case. Nice find, though.