# IE11, conflicting overflow and absolute position inside display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout

I'm working on a HTML layout with side-by-side panels containing separately scrollable contents:

**[See JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/agib/bk4yr0pe/)**

Things look as aspected in Chrome, Firefox and Safari (for Windows).

However, in *IE11*, the panel contents don't stretch to bottom of the panels.

It seems to have to do with `overflow-y: auto;` vs `position: absolute;` inside the `display: table-cell;` container.

**Any suggestions on how to fix this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE display: table-cell child ignores height: 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100)

Comment: Thanks. It's not exactly the same - I'm using absolute positioning instead of height: 100%. However, the issues may be related.