# <div> with height in percentage has 0 height when inside table-cell in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, height, zero

I want two vertically stacked empty divs (to display background images) to share exactly 50% of the height of the parent container minus a fixed gap (e.g. 20px). I'm using calc() for this - as Opera Mini doesn't matter in my case.

I got this working fine on all browsers:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%:
}
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
#top {
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
#bottom {
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

See JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Miglosh/bvndkw5y/

But, as a next step, I want to put this container next to another container holding a third image roughly double the size. For this, I use a parent container with display:table and two divs with display:table-cell.

```css
#contact-pics {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}
.table_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.table_cell:first-child {
  width: 66.666666%;
  padding-right: 14px;
}
.table_cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 33.333333%;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#top {
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
#bottom {
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact-pics">
  <div class="table_cell">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1650x1022" />
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell small">
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="top"></div>
      <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

WORKS PERFECTLY FINE on iOS, Android Browser, Safari, Chrome....

But in FF and IE, the two smaller divs collapse and don't get displayed so you can't see the background.

Here's the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Miglosh/bp251n71/

What's the clue? I lost a whole day yesterday with this and still don't find the solution.

Thanks for your help,
Stefan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no solution. Obviously, the behavior of height with table-cells is not part of the spec.

Just found this thread: [IE display: table-cell child ignores height: 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100)

Nothing to be done. Good old JS to the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `display: flex;` instead of `display:table` will solve your issue.

```
#parent {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#contact-pics {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Check [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp251n71/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ketan. Works 80% on FF (the bottom of the large image and the bottom of the lower small image aren't aligned).
BUT, unfortunately doesn't work any more on Chrome, Safari and the rest...

Comment: You're a genius ;-) Works perfectly well now in FF. 
BUT the notorious IE still refuses to cooperate :-(

Comment: It is because it's parent required  height and width for IE. Currently in fiddle set in % which will not work if you set html 100% then it will display (But weird.) Check  http://jsfiddle.net/bp251n71/11/

Comment: Yes, that's really weird and annoying. But how could I solve this problem?