# IE11. Bad height element in the table

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My problem is simply, a have table with labels and image link. Why, in IE11, labels height is not 100%? In Chrome and FF is work.

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="a2">sad</a></td>
              <td>
                  <label>asdasdasd</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
                <td><a id="a2">sad</a></td>
                  <td>
                      <label>asdad</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/newxfcfw/

Element `<a>` it has a different height in each row, 50px is only example.

Comment: @Aks IE11 ............

Comment: No CSS? We don't have a crystal ball...

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE display: table-cell child ignores height: 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100)

Comment: Ok, I have seen you updated your question so deleted my comment but I don't have access to IE11 right now so cannot help. But you can inspect element in IE & try different `css` to find to actual issue.

Comment: @connexo I think he has included css in Fiddle link.

Comment: **You cannot use** `position: absolute:` in a table. The results are unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height in pixel:

```
label{
position:absolute;
display:block;
background:orange;
height:100%
```

}

```
label{
position:absolute;
display:block;
background:orange;
height:50px;
```

}

Comment: Element <a> it has a different height in each row, 50px is only example. I update fiddle.