# How can I make the height of a <div> inside a display: table-cell be 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a table in my HTML that uses display: table. In the row I have two cells with some top/bottom padding and inside those I have `<div>`s which can be a different height:

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding-top:1rem; padding-bottom: 1rem;">
       <div style="background-color: red;">
          <input ng-model="row.abc">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding-top:1rem; padding-bottom: 1rem;">
       <div style="background-color: blue;">
          <input ng-model="row.def">
          <input ng-model="row.ghi">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there some way that I can make the height of the red and the blue be equal? As it is now the red is just half the height of the blue. Note that I am not looking for something that would make the two inputs go inline. I'm looking for a way to make the red area expand in height to match whatever height the blue is and vice versa.

I would like this to work using modern browsers. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE display: table-cell child ignores height: 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100)

Comment: You can't using only CSS in IE, see the above.

Comment: Even using other browsers I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you drop the div inside the cell? Because this would work.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell" style="background-color: red;">
           <input type="text" value="test" />
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell" style="background-color: blue;">
              <input type="text" value="test" />
              <input type="text" value="test" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6vx7j8d/

Answer (score -2):

Is there a compelling reason to be using nested `<div>` elements rather than normal table elements?

In any case, you should be able to set `height: 100%` as a style for each table cell, to force each one to fill its container's vertical dimension.

Comment: It's the height of the <div> inside the table-cell that I need to set to 100%.  That unfortunately does not work.