# Add footer to page with no scroll

Tags: html, css

How do i add a footer to the code that always is at the bottom?
It should still not be possible to scroll besides the scroll in the left div. The footer should fill the entire width of the page.

**CSS**

```css
.Top {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 80px;
}

.Container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: overflow;
}

.Left,
.Right {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto; 
}

.Left {
    width: 65%;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 0 15px 90px 15px;
}

.Right {
    width: 35%;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="Top"></div>

<div class="Container">
<div class="Left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is 2 ways, using `display: table`

*Side note: The `display: table` version work on IE 11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari. Because of a [render issue in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100) and below, you'll need a fixed height on the footer and header and use calc() to set the height on the inner cell/div to make it scroll.*

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.tbl{
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row{
  display:table-row;
}
.row.expanded{
  height: 100%;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}
.container,
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  background: #0099cc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 75px;
}
.footer {
  background: #3a3a3a;
  height: 75px;
}

#left_col {
  background: orange none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
  .scrollwrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
    .scroll {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      overflow: auto;
    }
#right_col {
  background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell header">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row expanded">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="tbl content">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="left_col" class="cell">
            <div class="scrollwrap">
              <div class="scroll">
                long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
                long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
                long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
                long content last
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="right_col" class="cell"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the recommended, using `flexbox`, though with less browser support on older browsers

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex{
  display:flex;
}
.flex.column {
  flex-direction: column
}
.flexitem{
}
.container{
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  background: #0099cc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 75px;
}
.content{
  flex: 1;
}
.footer {
  background: #3a3a3a;
  height: 75px;
}
#left_col {
  background: orange none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#right_col {
  background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex column container">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="flex content">
    <div id="left_col">
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content last
    </div>
    <div id="right_col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use the Table code the content in the left col is hidden and it will not scroll.

Comment: @Stefan Updated with a version working on IE 11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari. Because of a [render issue in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100) and below, you'll need a fixed height on the footer and header and use calc() to set the height on the inner cell.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **Bootstrap** for this instead of writing own CSS classes. That will make your life easier. The following example will give you the solution.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```