# ie scrollable absolute table-cell

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I trying to create scrollable side menu.  I did it with table-cell.
 Here is my fiddle:     https://jsfiddle.net/y6aq3oub/3/
 Code:

```css
#container {
  display:table;
}
#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background-color:white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.absolute-menu {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
.column {
  display:table-cell;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#col1 {
  width:25%;
  background-color:red;
}
#col2 {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="col1" class="column">
    <div class="absolute-menu">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2" class="course-column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula     eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula     eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

But menu's height is zero in  IE8-IE11. I found several similar questions but their solutions didn't helped me

For example: [IE display: table-cell child ignores height: 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100/27384730#27384730)
Requirements:

- col1 height = col2 height
- col2 height is dynamic
- col1 overflow content should be scrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution https://jsfiddle.net/y6aq3oub/7/
have to use margins

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red; /* This will serve as a background for a menu. */
}

.absolute-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 25%; /* You'll have to sync this... */
}

.course-column {
  margin-left: 25%; /* ... and this. */
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background-color:white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```