# 100% height pseudo element on a table cell in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, pseudo-element

I am encountering an issue in IE9,10,11 where an `::after` pseudo element will not fill 100% of the height of it's `td` parent.

If the first column in the second row had two lines of text, the pseudo element would fill the full height with no problem. So, I figured that the issue was happening because the `td` was not filling the height of the `tr` but that isn't the case.

The first screenshot is Chrome and the second is IE9

[image] [image]

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Two<br/>Lines</td>
    <td>Two<br/>Lines</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One Line</td>
    <td>Two <br/>Lines</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

table td:first-child {
  position: relative;
}

table td:first-child::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/cbier/full/BjpaqB/

**P.S.** I am using an `::after` pseudo-element instead of borders for a special reason and it is a requirement

Thanks!

Comment: I found this issue in a slightly different form in these questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384433/ie-display-table-cell-child-ignores-height-100
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285595/height-100-percent-under-display-table-cell-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

May be using a single pseudo element for the whole table ?

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}
table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  position: relative;
}
table tr:first-child td:first-child:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 1000px;
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Two<br/>Lines</td>
    <td>Two<br/>Lines</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One Line</td>
    <td>Two <br/>Lines</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

An alternate way, with background : linear-gradient

```css
table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
table td:first-child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, orange 3px, transparent 3px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Two<br/>Lines</td>
    <td>Two<br/>Lines</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One Line</td>
    <td>Two <br/>Lines</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a clever idea! The only thing is that the table has a variable height, so a 100% height is still needed

Comment: In my example, I set overflow: hidden to the table, and then a huge height, greater than needed.You can change height: 1000px to 9999px, for instance

Comment: Thanks for the options but I've personally touched on that one already, too. I am looking for a less messy way to do it. Maybe there really is no way to make IE behave. Sorry I didn't notice that you used overflow hidden

Comment: I know that you said that it should be a pseudo... but the reason that you stated is that it couldn't be a border, so I posted a solution with gradients. That will leave IE9 out, but may be you can solve it with filters.. (I Can't test IE9)

Comment: Your solution was good the first time :) I just meant it couldn't use the `border` property since I'm using an image background on the pseduo element in my current scenario

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for it:

```
  table td:first-child::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 45px;
   display: block;
   background-color: orange;
 }
```

it is giving same output in `chrome`as well as `IE 9`

Comment: What is the difference between your code and the question code ?

Comment: I have used `height: 45px;` .

Comment: Unfortunately the height is variable on the rows so this wouldn't work. That's why I have to use 100% height in the first place. Thanks for taking the time to answer though !!