# Display:table-cell and font-size: strange behaviour on cells' height in Firefox

Tags: css, tablecell

I have a strange behaviour with DIV-Table

Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fp6cfwb4/) with my simplified example. Relevant part of CSS is the following:

.cell
{
   display: table-cell;
   width:35px;
   height:12px;
   font-size:1px;
   overflow:hidden;
   line-height:1em;
}

Actually, `font-size` is set to `1px`.

In **Firefox**, if *I increase font-size (with inspector for example) until `13px`, cells' height decrease instead of increase*. Over this threshold, cells' height start to increase to accomodate test strings. `height` property seems completely ignored.

In Chrome, beahaviour is almost one desired (increasing `font-size` results in a continuous cells' height increase) but, again, `height` property seems completely ignored.

If I don't set `display: table-cell;`, increase of `font-size` does not affect DIVs' height and eventually too big text is simply hidden thanks to `overflow:hidden`.

---

**UPDATE:**

I just [discovered](http://jsfiddle.net/fp6cfwb4/1/) that forcing `vertical-align` makes Firefox behaviour similar to Chrome one (cells' height remains fixed until text fit inside them). I don't know why, but seems that for Firefox is necessary to force this property.

Anyway, remain the other need: how to avoid that increasing `font-size` over `13px` will results in ignoring cells `height`, and auto-adjust it?

Comment: Thanks to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428121/height100-inside-table-cell-not-working-on-firefox-and-ie) I can add only that setting `height:100%;` to `table-cell` makes height of DIV dependent only by `font-size` in Firefox too. But is not the solution. I would like to mantain FIXED div's height.

Comment: The standard behaviour of table cells is that they grow with their content, even if you set a height. So a cell with `height:20px` and a content of 30px high will increase itself to 30px high. That is normal and expected behaviour. On the other hand, the bit where the height decreases if you increase the font size is very strange. It could even be a bug...

Comment: Yes, I can understand first part of your answer, but like you said... is very strange the second behaviour.... maybe someone has some explanation?