# How to expand a div inside a td with a height in a row that is too big

Tags: html, css

I have a table where cells have a fixed height. In one of the cells there is a tall element that makes one row expand vertically. And there is another cell with a div element that is set to 100% the height of the cell. I would like to make this div element expand vertically to the cell height, further than the original set height of the cell. How can I do this?

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:50px; background:green">Tall element</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="background:yellow;height:100%">Should expand</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you make a drawing?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question..

Comment: The current example does it already in Chrome, but not in Firefox. For everyone wondering, what the sryscad wants.

Comment: A working solution is provided by the accepted answer to [How to make <div> fill <td> height in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36576083/5841606)

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic div filling `100% height` is required on the parent container. To solve this, we can set the `30px` as `min-height` and create a div CSS property to `inherit` the `height`.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height:30px;
}
div {
height: inherit;
   }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:50px; background:green">Tall element</div>
    </td>
    <td >
      <div style="background:yellow;">Should expand</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```