# How to set 100% height of div inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a div inside a table cell to fill the entire height of the table cell. The div is a "wrapper" div (bookWrapper) with 3 other divs inside. I need the footer div (bookNavLinks) inside the wrapper div to stick to the bottom. I tried setting the height to 100% and position relative. bookNavLinks position is set to absolute and bottom 0;

```
<div id="bookWrapper" style="height:100%; border:1px solid #000; position:relative;">

<div id="bookNavLinks" style="padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px; position:absolute; bottom:0">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5zg4h95o/3/

Comment: Any particular reasons why you are using a table to achieve your design layout? far from the best way of doing things

Comment: To add to @Tik's comment, I would strongly encourage moving away from the tables for layout and inline-css approach you have going on, if you have any serious aspirations to pursue front end development

Comment: I absolutely agree with both these comments. However, we don't know the end use... and if it is for HTML email, table layouts tend to render more consistently across various [email clients](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Demo - codepen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/WOqrxq?editors=1010)

[Here's another relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7600749/4881490)

It appears you need to add a height to the `<table>` tag.

`<table style="border-collapse: collapse; height:100%">`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Joe B.'s comment.

Instead of `height: 100%`, I use `height: 1px`. Because with 100% table stretches when I don't have enough rows in it.