# How can I make the sort click target the full height of the table heading cell?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

How can I make the entire blue rectangle clickable for the sorting thing? I mean, if the text is pretty short, I can only click around the text, but not anywhere inside the blue area. The entire blue area for the "Bla-bla-bla" thing is clickable most likely because the text is already very long.

You can see the issue here: https://streamable.com/h2jugw

How can I fix this? Any ideas?

P.S.: I tried to see the answers posted here: [Make a DIV fill an entire table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215553/make-a-div-fill-an-entire-table-cell) but I have no idea which answer can help me... There's not a single response that refers to sort click targeting the full height of the table heading cell... :/ Please help me. :(

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
            <style>
        .bgcolor {
          background-color: #06AEF8;
        }
        .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table {
    table-layout: fixed;
          border-color: #A2A9B1 !important;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .both {
          background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.56'%3E%3Cpolygon points='50,10 70,45 30,45'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='30,55 70,55 50,90' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
          background-size: 19px, 19px;
          white-space: inherit;
          word-break: break-word;
        }
        .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .asc {
          background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.69'%3E%3Cpolygon points='50,10 70,45 30,45'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
          background-size: 19px, 19px;
        }
        .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .desc {
          background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.69'%3E%3Cpolygon points='30,55 70,55 50,90' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
          background-size: 19px, 19px;
        }
        .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
          background-color: #B9B9B9; 
        }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <table data-toggle="table" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bgcolor">
                            <th data-sortable="true" data-sort-order="desc" class="align-middle">Test</th>
                            <th data-sortable="true" data-sort-order="desc" class="align-middle">Bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-blaBla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-blaBla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla</th>
                            <th data-sortable="true" data-sort-order="desc" class="align-middle">Another test</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>A</td>
                            <td>B</td>
                            <td>C</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>E</td>
                            <td>F</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>H</td>
                            <td>I</td>
                            <td>J</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use anchor tag **a** inside each table header tag **th**. And we can add some CSS classes to set width and height of table header cell.

The following snippet of code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .bgcolor {
      background-color: #06AEF8;
    }

    .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table {
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-color: #A2A9B1 !important;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .both {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.56'%3E%3Cpolygon points='50,10 70,45 30,45'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='30,55 70,55 50,90' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      background-size: 19px, 19px;
      white-space: inherit;
      word-break: break-word;
    }

    .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .asc {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.69'%3E%3Cpolygon points='50,10 70,45 30,45'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      background-size: 19px, 19px;
    }

    .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .desc {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.69'%3E%3Cpolygon points='30,55 70,55 50,90' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      background-size: 19px, 19px;
    }

    .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
    .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
      background-color: #B9B9B9;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table data-toggle="table" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr class="bgcolor">
          <th data-sortable="true" data-sort-order="desc" class="align-middle">
            <a href="#" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
              Test
            </a>
          </th>
          <th data-sortable="true" data-sort-order="desc" class="align-middle">
            <a href="#" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
              Bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-blaBla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-blaBla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla
            </a>
          </th>
          <th data-sortable="true" data-sort-order="desc" class="align-middle">
            <a href="#" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
              Another test
            </a>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>E</td>
          <td>F</td>
          <td>G</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>H</td>
          <td>I</td>
          <td>J</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I ran your snippet, but it doesn't address my issue.