# How to make div appear in front of another?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:300px; z-index:1; background-color:red;">
    <ul style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:800px; z-index:2; background-color:blue;">
        <li>
            <div style="height:500px; background-color:black; position:relative; z-index:3;">
            This is div
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

1st question - From the above codes, the webpage shows 300px height of `<ul>` and 300px height of `<div>` only, how to make the webpage shows 800 height of `<ul>` and 500px height of `<div>` without changing overflow property and without changing the height of 1st `<div>`(300px)? Already got the answer from Omabena. I just need to change position of 1st div to static and ul to absolute.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; position:static; height:300px;  background-color:red;">
<ul style=" position: absolute; overflow:hidden; height:1500px; background-color:blue;">
    <li>
        <table><tr><td>
            <div style="height:500px; background-color:black; position:static; z-index:3;">
                This is 2nd div
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="height:500px; background-color:green; position:relative; z-index:3;">
                This is 3rd div
            </div>
        </td></tr></table>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

2nd question - From the above codes, how to make the webpage shows 300px height of 2nd div and 500px height of 3rd div. I mean the 2nd div must hide inside the 1st div which has 300px height only.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to try absolute positioning.

Comment: I tested the position:absolute, end up all divs and ul are gone, the webpage shows empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; height:300px;  background-color:red;">
<ul style=" position: absolute;overflow:hidden; height:800px; background-color:blue;">
    <li>
        <div style="height:500px; background-color:black; position:relative; z-index:3;">
        This is div
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure if that makes it for you.

Comment: Wow. Cool. I guess I know what is my problem already. Thank you. I have other question, please refer to my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: The second question looks pretty tricky to me, not sure how to accomplish that without changing your html markup or breaking the natural flow of CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:800px; z-index:1; background-color:red;">
    <ul style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:800px; z-index:2; background-color:blue;">
    <br/>
        <li>
            <div style="height:500px; background-color:white; position:relative; z-index:3;">
            This is div
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how about without changing the height of 1st `<div>`(300px)? I have updated my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer already exists.

[Position an HTML element relative to its container using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css)

Comment: no, the answer is not exists, the link that you show me is about the left, top, position property which is not related to my question.

Answer (score 0):

dose the div have to be nested can you use a container div and have you 1st div and UL at the same level then use position:absolute on the two

Comment: i have no idea what are you talking about. Yes, I can use a container div. What is "have you 1st div at the same level" mean?