# Position Inline Element Relative to Container

Tags: html, css, positioning

I want an element in HTML to be positioned relative to it's parent, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css), but using inline.

I have [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVBmQ/) to demonstrate. For this example, I would like the textbox to cover the text (using `margin:0;`, not a negative value.

Can it be done?

Comment: can u post result images

Comment: you want to hide text? I mean you want text box on your text?

Comment: @krish you didn't saved your fiddle

Comment: @JNF something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vVBmQ/2/)

Comment: @JNF am posting it as my answer you can mark it correct so that others can refer it directly, I posted it as a comment because I was not getting your question properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `position:relative;` and `position: absolute;` like this :

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVBmQ/2/)

Or just use `left: 0px;` instead of `margin` but make sure that the parent `div` to be `positioned` `relative`

Comment: It was actually the `left:0;` that did the trick, but you helped me hit the answer.

Comment: You should probably edit the answer to include that detail... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <input value="Text" />
</div>
​
```

Or are you using this for something other than inputs?

Since you're already using absolute positioning, you could just do `left: 0`.

Comment: I need the `Text` where it is - not inside the `input`.

Comment: So you want to stack inline elements using relative positioning and no negative margins?