# Unable to align nested divs properly

Tags: css, html

I have one main div (page) which has another internal div (central). I applied CSS for both the divs. I gave the margin-top attribute for both the divs separately in CSS, but the margin-top of the internal div is being applied to external div also. How can I fix this problem?

CSS:

```
#page
{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #b3dced;
    height: 900px;
    width: 900px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.central
{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[Align the divs fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/saimadanmohan/269Pw/)

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div class="central">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: here's one way to do it - http://jsfiddle.net/269Pw/4/

Comment: @MElliott can you explain how it is working in a brief manner

Comment: @saimadan margins doesn't collapse on inline-block elements...Review my answer and the article I link

Comment: @Danko thanks i didn't know so far a concept called margin collapsing exists i'm studying the article now..

Comment: Yes, Danko is correct.  I didn't feel like writing a whole explanation so that's why I just put an example in comment, but @Danko's answer is a good answer!  :)

Comment: It's a tricky concept and as far I know can have many faces . . . but with those articles you can make an idea why this happen.

Comment: yeah very well explained and good reference as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That issue is known as [`Margin Collapsing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

> When the vertical margins of two elements are touching, only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be honored, while the margin of the element with the smaller margin value will be collapsed to zero.

You could avoid that using `padding` or `top` on the child element. Or add a little padding on the parent. Like this:

```
#page {
  padding-top:1px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/269Pw/6/.

On this [**Article**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) you can find more about this issue and many ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. Details are in Stack Overflow post *[Position an HTML element relative to its container using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953)* about using `position: relative`.

But sometimes it is easier to learn based on your own code:

```
#page
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #B3DCED;
    height: 900px;
    width: 900px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.central
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```