# Why does video return to blurry thumb at end?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, thumbnails

I have rel=0 in my embed code so when the video ends it returns to the start. But it's displaying the thumbnail for the video, after returning, with the thumbnail blown up to the full video size, so the image is extremely blurry. How can I get the full 1280 x 720 image I uploaded for the thumb to be displayed?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your full embed code (with the videoID) so others might be able to look into it?

Comment: You can view the video by clicking the "Introduction to Zackel" video at zackel.com and see the problem there when the video ends.  The embed code used there is <iframe width=853 height=480 src=//www.youtube.com/embed/LqeN31x-5gE?rel=0&autoplay=1&rel=0 frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: The page is working now the way I would expect, with the 1280x720 image being displayed when the video ends and goes back to the beginning. ???!!!.  I didn't change anything.

Comment: Sometimes those types of backend issues happen, and then the engineers work them out. Glad it's all in order for you now!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying.  What engineers, in this case, do you think worked it out?  Do you think YouTube became aware of the issue and fixed it?

Comment: Possibly, if it were widespread (although I didn't see anything in the bug tracker). IT could have also been a tangential issue that was caused by something else they were working on, or a misconfiguration in a server somewhere, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd give you the points but I don't think I can assign them to a comment.

Comment: No need -- I didn't really do anything to solve the problem! Best of luck to you.

Comment: It still looks quite ugly in my browser: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c031r90d1. Or is this how it should be?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to look. Previously is was a thumbnail blown up to screen size so it appeared blurry. This at least has the full resolution.  Just curious - what would make it less ugly, in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for example, detect when the video has ended and then overlay the video with your image. For example:

#### HTML:

```
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<div id='yt_container'>
    <iframe id='element_id' width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/LqeN31x-5gE?autoplay=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;rel=0&amp;start=248" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <!--Seems like people always forget to encode & as &amp;-->
    <!--The "start" parameter was added for easier testing-->
    <!--The `enablejsapi=1` parameter is required for this to work. For more information, see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
    <div  id='player_overlay_image'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
iframe,img,div{/*If you use this on a real web page, you will want to make these rules more specific*/
    padding:0;
    margin:0        
}

div#yt_container{
    position:relative;/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/105035/1419007 */
}
```

```
div#player_overlay_image{/* The high-resolution image for when your video has ended. Includes a ▶ button. */
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 29px;
    background: url('//i.imgur.com/JhDUWdI.png');
    width:853px;
    height:408px;
    display: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

div#player_overlay_image:hover{/* ▶ button in active state. */
    background: url(//i.imgur.com/ljKjsD4.png);
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var yt_player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    yt_player = new YT.Player('element_id', {
    events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
        //Display overlay image
        document.getElementById('player_overlay_image').style.display='block';
    }
}

document.getElementById('player_overlay_image').addEventListener('click', function(evt){                                                         
    //Hide overlay image
    document.getElementById('player_overlay_image').style.display='none';

    //Play video
    yt_player.playVideo();
}, false);
```

(See the [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for more information.)

http://jsfiddle.net/y3Xqj/1/

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I hope you  finish it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it didn't got solved by itself.  This is how I solved the issue:

I used the youtube iframe api and rewinded the video to the start once the video ended, that way the thumbnail looks good as it was when the page loaded.

`YoutubeF` is the iframe id.

**Code:**

```
var YTplayer;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
{
    YTplayer = new YT.Player('YoutubeF', { events: { 'onStateChange': onYTPlayerStateChange } });
}

function onYTPlayerStateChange(event)
{
    if (event.data == 0)
    {
        YTplayer.seekTo(0, false)
    }
}
```

Enjoy!