# HTML elements do not position as expected

Tags: html, positioning

I am dynamically assembling `divs within divs` and adding text to each internal div - building a list with a Javascript list adapter.  The internal `list divs` display as desired, but the respective `text divs` in each `list div` does not:

Example:

[image]

As you can see in the image the `text div` on the right in red text is slightly higher than the one on the left in green.  I have set the properties for each as such:

In Javascript I add them in a loop using the following:

```
var divGreen = document.createElement("div");
divGreen.style.position = "relative";
divGreen.style.width = "10%";
divGreen.style.left = "100%";
divGreen.style.top = "100%";
divGreen.style.marginLeft = "-40%";
divGreen.style.marginTop = "-20%";
divGreen.style.color = "green";
divGreen.style.textAlign="left";
divGreen.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";                 
divGreen.innerHTML = 'Text';
div.appendChild(divGreen);



var divRed = document.createElement("div");
divRed.style.position = "relative";
divRed.style.width = "10%";
divRed.style.left = "100%";
divRed.style.top = "100%";
divRed.style.marginLeft = "-20%";
divRed.style.marginTop = "-20%";
divRed.style.color = "red";
divRed.style.textAlign="left";
divRed.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";                   
divRed.innerHTML = 'Text';
div.appendChild(divRed);
```

Also, the literal `Text` is used to eliminate character size differences.

Why do they not line up vertically as expected?  What am I missing?

Comment: I deleted that comment. I relaized exactly what was worng. Sorry.

Comment: Where do you define `div` and is that div appended to the body?

Comment: `div` resides in a defined container that has an absolute position - this is displayed in the correct location and as desired.

Comment: Alright one final thing. I am having trouble replicating your problem so that I can fix it. Perhaps you could do a jsfiddle? Because I have to remove the negative values in order to get it to display...

Comment: Specifically everything else on that page that could have an impact on the positioning of said divs.

Comment: Since I am defining them as `relative`, the only thing that should have an impact is the parent container - which is displaying correctly (as expected).  I don't know how anything else could impact the divs in question in the way you suggest.

Comment: What's really curious is the base metric of `top` and `marginTop` should be identical across all elements in the container.  But, they don't appear to be!!!

Comment: I think it may be because the webpage is, in effect, infinite and that you can't have 20% of infinity from the top if the end of the webpage is undefined. Try a specific unit like pixels?

Comment: I am sorry but i prefer to see a fully working example because I use the DOM Inspector to see what attributes cancel out and what ones take effect on certain items on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css) - It's clear my understanding of absolute positioning was wrong.  By setting the position absolute on the parent, I can use absolute positioning of it's children relative to the parent.  **The key is the parent having position set to absolute!**

```
var divGreen = document.createElement("div");
divGreen.style.position = "absolute";
divGreen.style.width = "10%";
divGreen.style.left = "100%";
divGreen.style.top = "37px";
divGreen.style.marginLeft = "-40%";
divGreen.style.color = "green";
divGreen.style.textAlign="left";
divGreen.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";                 
divGreen.innerHTML = 'Text';
div.appendChild(divGreen);



var divRed = document.createElement("div");
divRed.style.position = "absolute";
divRed.style.width = "10%";
divRed.style.left = "100%";
divGreen.style.top = "37px";
divRed.style.marginLeft = "-20%";
divRed.style.color = "red";
divRed.style.textAlign="left";
divRed.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";                   
divRed.innerHTML = 'Text';
div.appendChild(divRed);
```

Now my links are aligned vertically as intended:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had this happen to me. I was able to put my code in a table.

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>
              html code here
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

TR means table row and td is table data

Comment: I don't think that's what he is looking for. He is talking about nested `<div>`'s not tables.

Comment: You must be new to programming.

Comment: Just trying to help :(

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but tables are too heavy handed for the situation.  I really want to understand why the `divs` are not displaying as I expect?

Comment: You gotta know what the person is asking to give them a helpful answer. You may mean well but if you aren't sure what's going on in the code it won't be very helpful. So next time if you dont really know what's going on, try answering questions you do. When you get yourself a reputation of 15 you can be more helpful by just voting up questions to make them more visible to the community. @Zoogy1983