# How could I keep the same format of unordered list and move it to centre

Tags: css, positioning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdLtS.jpg)

I would like to keep the formatting of unordered lists the same as in the screenshot attached. But I would like to position it all to the center. How do I accomplish that? Bear in mind I already used text-align: left. Is there any other way to center apart of adding left element and adding values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position an HTML element relative to its container using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 30%; margin-left: 35%">
    <ul>
        <li>Some text</li>
        <li>Some text with other text</li>
        <li>Some text with other text plus more text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ok? =)

Comment: oAAAsoome :) Thank you so much